# How do I search within an list of strings in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch

My data has a field localities which is an array of strings.

```
"localities": [
"Mayur Vihar Phase 1",
"Paschim Vihar",
"Rohini",
"",
"Laxmi Nagar",
"Vasant Vihar",
"Dwarka",
"Karol Bagh",
"Inderlok"  ]
```

What query should I write to filter the documents by a specific locality such as "Rohini"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `match` query will be enough (if you don't know the mapping of your `localities` field).

```
POST <your index>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "localities": "Rohini"
    }
  }
}
```

If the `localities` field is set as a `string` type and `index` as `not_analyzed`, the best way to query this is to use a `term` filter, wrapped in a `filtered` query (you can't use directly filters) :

```
POST <your index>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "localities": "Rohini"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you doesn't need the score, the second solution is the way to go as filters doesn't compute score, are faster and cached.

Check the documentation for information about analysis which is a very important subject in ElasticSearch, heavily influencing the way you query.

Answer (score 0):

```
POST /_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "localities": "Rohini"
    }
  }
}
```

Or you can simply query:

```
GET /_search?q=localities:Rohini
```

Comment: A GET request doesn't work as the query body isn't used. If you use Sense, beware as it transform automatically the request to a POST (you can check it by monitoring the outgoing request) if it a body is provided.

Comment: Yes, Sense tranforms it automaticaly. 
With `curl` you should use POST.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, Forza for your answers.